# Can't get Idxmax to work for specific course question

Tags: python, pandas

This was the first questions which has been logged as correct

[image]

The second part of the question I have attempted multiple ways to get this after trying the initial way that the course material suggested me to do so but keep getting hit with an error. Any thoughts behind what is preventing idxmax function from working?

[image]

Comment: You're currently getting the `idxmax` of the whole table, the instructions tell you to get it for a specific column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your code is:

df.Close.idxmax() then it will fetch you the date with highest Closing price

In the above, default axis is "row" or axis=0

if your code is:
df.loc[:,["High","Open","Low"]].idxmax() then this will fetch three row of data like the below:

High   2018-01-13 21:00:00
Open   2018-01-13 21:00:00
Low    2018-01-13 18:00:00

if you code is:
df.loc[:,["High","Close","Open","Low"]].idxmax(axis=1)
this will fetch you the name of the column in each row having the highest value. Here if your data contains 2100 rows then result will have 2100 rows revealing the name of the column containing the max value.

Bottom line is IDXmax accepts only numerical values. It will throw error if you put "numeric_only" argument inside idxmax function.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I just didn't understand why the link we were sent said it needed to include the 'numeric_only' argument. Will give it a go tomorrow!

Comment: I just checked the pandax documentation for IDXMAX function, it do have an argument "mumeric_only"; however, I tried to use this argument, but pandas throws error.